# Job navigates to one page and does not count down pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I'm navigating to all the links on this [page](https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/football), but the page counter is not working.  Any idea why that is?

I've tried to adjust the xpath in the hopes that would fix the issue.  Why is it doing this?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def page_counter():
  for x in range(1000):
      yield x

count = page_counter()
driver.get('https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/football')
elements = [x.get_attribute("href") for x in
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//nav//a[starts-with(@href, ('football'))]")]
shuffle(elements)

import operator

import collections
links = dict((next(count) + 1, e) for e in elements)

desc_links = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(links.items(), reverse=True))

for key, value in desc_links.items():
    driver.get(value)
    print('At Page: ' + str(key))
```

Comment: `'page counter is not working'` is not a precise definition of the problem. Please update your question with samples of expected vs actual outputs.

Comment: @quamrana output is blank, not navigating to pages.  Stops when it is expected to navigate...

Comment: When I tested the parts of your code just concerned with the page counter, everything seemed to work - it reversed the order of the pages. You need to do a separate investigation into the exchange with the website.

Comment: @quamrana I suspect maybe it's an indent or something else causing issue if it worked for you.  How strange.  I rewrote script and same issue

Comment: What `driver.chrome()` suppose to do?

Comment: @Andersson That's a typo.  I edited to driver = webdriver.Chrome()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*`elements` becomes an empty list* and that is the reason your loop is not working.

You need to *let your page load* to be able to access the link elements which have `href` starting with `football`. One of the possible ways to do it would be using [`WebDriverWait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to wait for the header element to be visible:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/football')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".container .page-content header")))

elements = [x.get_attribute("href") for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//nav//a[starts-with(@href, ('football'))]")]
```